# getContentResolver() Returns all rows of table and updates none

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am using following statement to update a row in the Content provider's table.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ReminderData.REMINDERS_STATUS, Boolean.valueOf(isChecked));
mCtx.getContentResolver().update(ReminderData.CONTENT_URI, values, ReminderData._ID + "=?", new String[]{cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderData._ID))});
```

Values:

```
ReminderData.CONTENT_URI : content://com.android.firstapp.data/reminder
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderData._ID)) : 2
```

I always get the result as 0, i.e. 0 rows updated. But I have a row in the table with id 2.

Also when I try to retrieve a row from the content provider using below code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ReminderData.CONTENT_URI, null, ReminderData._ID+"=?", new String[] {id+""}, null);\
```

id value is 3. 
But I get all the rows in the cursor with cursor count as 5.

I don't know what is the issue. Please help. TIA.

Comment: Seems you are dealing with custom content provider. Nobody can answer you without observing you content provider implementation.

Comment: It would help if you posted the rest of your code where you retrieve the data from the cursor